# 'Motion' port not responding - "This site can't be reached"

Tags: raspbian, webcam, motion, dns, port-forwarding

I've set up my Pi as a web server and I am using RaspCTL as the dynamic DNS. I can access my site via [mysite].raspctl.com from my home network and from an external network. Great!

I'm also trying to broadcast from my webcam using the `Motion` library. I've followed tutorials to set it up and I've modified the config file appropriately, per the instructions in [this tutorial on pimylifeup.com](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/). I've left it using port 8081. However, when I go to [mysite].raspctl.com:8081 I see the following message in Chrome:

`This site can’t be reached`

`[mysite].raspctl.com refused to connect.`

I believe I've opened port 8081 on my router and it's pointing to my Pi. What am I missing? Thanks!!

Comment: You can use something like [canyouseeme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) to test whether that port is in fact visible to the rest of the world. It would be helpful, if you're following a tutorial, to post either a link to or a copy of your configuration settings.

Comment: @goobering I used [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/) tutorial to set it up with the same config described there

Comment: Did you check if your port's open?

Comment: @goobering Unfortunately I can't do that until I'm home! I'll do that asap though

Comment: @goobering The connection is refused...